# Is there a good integer only line rasterization algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, rasterizing

I've been working on building a simple 3d graphic engine and I'm trying to find a good integer based line rasterization algorithm. ( I'm not trying to re-invent the wheel, I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of wheels).

Are there any line rasterizing algorithms that don't rely on any floating point math?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) is integer only.